# Looping sql Query with ajax to update data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database-performance

I'm working and creating a messenger like app now, I just want to ask

It it advisable to loop an ajax that queries data from MYSQL, to have an updated data for my messages?

I want page data to be updated every time there is a new message from the sender, the receiver will receive the data without reloading the page, and my approach for this is to loop my ajax query that gets all the messages for the receiver or sender from my sql table.

Q2. Will this affects the performance of my database?

Q3. Is there any other way to do this? I'm currently working with php now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a few users, no problem.  If you have more than, say, 10K users sitting in that loop, you might start smelling smoke come out of the database server.

For large scale deployment, I think you need something "push" technology outside the realm of AJAX, PHP, and MySQL.

One AJAX call will lead to

1. Web server sees the request, and hands it to
2. PHP which starts up as a "child" to the web server; then PHP
3. Connects to MySQL, and
4. Performs a query, and
5. PHP replies to
6. AJAX, which either puts up the message or sleeps for another second;
   7,8 Meanwhile, MySQL and PHP shutdown.

That's a lot of steps; I am not sure which part will be the worst.  But, assuming everything is running on a single machine, there are limits to how many users it will support.

Comment: so what technology can I use instead?